# transfer two existing taxonomy terms into one custom metabox

Tags: custom-taxonomy, theme-development, taxonomy, metabox

Using this code I am able to add existing `Terms` from one taxonomy `moviestax` to my own created Metabox.

```
function my_meta_box(){
    add_meta_box( 'mymtx_div', 'This my own Meta box Only :-)', 'post_categories_meta_box', 'post', 'normal', 'high', array( 'taxonomy' => 'moviestax' ));
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_meta_box', 0 );
```

Now I just wonder if there is a way to add another existing taxonomy like `bookstax` terms to the new metabox or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_meta_box(){
    add_meta_box( 'mymtx_div', 'This my own Meta box Only :-)', 'post_categories_meta_box', 'post', 'normal', 'high', array( 'taxonomy' => array(0=>'moviestax', 1=> 'bookstax') ));
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_meta_box', 0 );
function post_categories_meta_box(){}
```

This example migth help you.

Comment: Hi Maxim, I am getting this error inside the metabox Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in `D:\wamp64\www\WP\wp-includes\taxonomy.php on line 259`

Comment: Yes, because previously `moviestax` was string, now one keys in array. Early was `$taxonomy = "moviestax''` and now `$taxonomy= array(0 => 'moviestax', 1 => 'bookstax')`

Comment: Now I am getting 3 errors: one in the `Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in D:\wamp64\www\WP\wp-includes\taxonomy.php on line 259` and second and third are ` `Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given in D:\wamp64\www\WP\wp-admin\includes\template.php on line 156`

Comment: Show me your code inside callback function. And see how use array in callback_args in [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/)

Comment: Ok Now I am lost! I didnt use any callback function

Comment: in `add_meta_box()` third parameter - is a callback function. Last parameter - callback_args. See documentation.

Comment: I am affraid Maxim but I have one empty function for call back! `function post_categories_meta_box(){}`

Comment: The `post_categories_meta_box` is actually a builtin function in `meta-boxes.php`

Comment: Ok Maxim can you please give me a hint how I can access the arrays value inside the callback function?

Comment: I gave link on official documentation.

Comment: I couldn't find any thing similar to what I have here!

Comment: How can I access to callback_args in call back function?

Comment: Tried this ` $args = array_map( 'esc_html', $callback_args['args'] );
        return print "<h2>".implode( ' ', $args )."</h2>";` but I am only getting string of Array

Comment: Also tried this one `    echo $metabox['args']['moviestax'];` but nothing display on the metabox

Comment: try var_dump($callback_args) and var_dump($metabox['args']);